# How to intercept UIWebView URL resource requests

Tags: ios, url, uiwebview

This was really hard to figure out but I think I have figured it out successfully. This code can be useful if you are trying to build a progress indicator, for example, or do something at some point in the lifecycle of loading a page.

With this code, you can now see every URL that is being downloaded, whether that is an image, a css file, etc.

```
@interface CustomURLProtocol : NSURLProtocol
@end

@implementation CustomURLProtocol

+ (void)enable
{
    [NSURLProtocol registerClass:[CustomURLProtocol class]];
}

+ (BOOL)canInitWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
{
    // Do something here with request.URL.absolutestring

    return NO;
}

@end
```

Now, just call [CustomURLProtocol enable].

Comment: No question. Just sharing info. Did I post this wrongly?

Comment: Yep. You should post questions.